# How to properly set variables in a latex template for Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, latex

I want to create a pdf with latex through a django view. I created the view and set up a latex template and it works fine except for one thing. When I place a variable in the latex template I have to use spaces around the curly brackets like so:

```
\somevalue{ {{variable}} }
```

Otherwise django won't check that it is as a variable. The latex syntax checker already tells me "Unintendes whitespace around }?!". I can pass the variable into the template through my view and the pdf get created but then I have whitespaces around the inserted text.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: This is especally trouble some when specifying a path for instance. I tried `{% spaceless %}\includegraphics[width=200pt]{ {{ logo_pdf }} } {% endspaceless %}` but `spaceless` is only for html. It would require a custom similar tag for latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to remove extra spaces after template rendering:

```
template = select_template(self.get_template_names())
latex_content = template.render(context)
latex_content = re.sub(r'\{ ', '{', latex_content)
latex_content = re.sub(r' \}', '}', latex_content)
```

This has the benefit of not requiring extra template tags flooding the template. However this as the drawback to require template writers to be aware of this behavior and take it into account wherever curly braces are used.

In practice, it would probably be better to write a custom Template class that handles this.

**Edit**

Note that using this method, there is no reason to use a space as separator rather than any other character. In order to make it clearer for template writers/readers, you can use another character that would ring him a bell. For instance:

template.tex

```
\somevalue{§{{ variable }}§}
```

views.py

```
template = select_template(self.get_template_names())
latex_content = template.render(context)
latex_content = re.sub(r'\{§', '{', latex_content)
latex_content = re.sub(r'§\}', '}', latex_content)
```

Which makes it clear that if there is a space, it is intended. And I think it's already clear that `§` everywhere is not intended to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. It sounds logical, but unfortunately I cannot "access" the rendered template. I get the error that I can't use a string method on a binary object...

Comment: I guess you do something like `latex_content = template.render(context).encode('utf-8')`. Just call `.encode('utf-8')` after the substitution.

Comment: You're right. It works well... I actually prefer this method now, since I'm having trouble getting Jinja to work with CSRF... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Based on some google research, I'd recommend switching templating engines to Jinja, which is supported by Django and has configurable syntax.
Be warned, I haven't fully tested this.

Here's how your latex templates would look like:

```
\somevalue{((variable))}
```

The most important part is setting the `variable_start_string` and `variable_end_string` options:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> env = jinja2.Environment(variable_start_string='((', variable_end_string='))')
>>> t = env.from_string("\somevalue{((variable))}")
>>> t.render(name='Attention!')
'\\somevalue{Attention!}'
```

[Jinja's switching documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/switching/#django) outlines the (few) syntax differences. From the FAQ:

> The default syntax of Jinja2 matches Django syntax in many ways. However this similarity doesn’t mean that you can use a Django template unmodified in Jinja2. For example filter arguments use a function call syntax rather than a colon to separate filter name and arguments. Additionally the extension interface in Jinja is fundamentally different from the Django one which means that your custom tags won’t work any longer.

[Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/) and 1.8 and maybe other versions have built-in support for Jinja.

I haven't found an example of configuring Jinja syntax in Django, and I can't test this at the moment but I believe you need to change the
`TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']` dictionary as needed:

```
    block_start_string='(#',
    block_end_string='#)',
    variable_start_string='((',
    variable_end_string='))',
    comment_start_string='((#',
    comment_end_string='#))',
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked - after some configuration problems - like a charme and the pdf gets created without any unnecessary whitespaces. Do you have any idea if it is possible to create a dictionary with all my variables and pass the dictionary in the jinja render function (as with Djangos Context)?